# Learning German scripts (handwriting and printing) used in 19th century records

Tags: 19th-century, germany, palaeography

In my related question about [finding parish records in Saxony, Germany](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6616/finding-online-parish-records-in-saxony-germany/6617#6617) lejonet reminded me about other resources for [Werdau](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&placeId=55319&query=%2Bplace%3A%22Germany%2C%20Sachsen%2C%20Werdau%20%28AH.%20Zwickau%29%22) in the Family History Catalog.

The Family History Library has resident population registers, documentations of origin, and citizen rolls.  Before I order the microfilms, I'd like to familiarize myself with the forms of these records, which includes learning how to read them.

What tutorials exist for learning how to read old German handwriting, and books printed in older German typescripts?  If you taught yourself how to read it, what techniques (e.g. flash cards) worked for you?

Answer (score 5):

I read the German translation of *Minert, Roger P. Deciphering Handwriting in German Documents: Analyzing German, Latin, and French in Vital Records Written in Germany. Provo, Utah: GRT Publications, 2001.* and think it is even more helpful to someone not familiar with German language than it was for me.

There is also a [BYU tutorial](https://script.byu.edu/Pages/the-german-documents-pages/the-german-documents(english)) I can recommend.

Answer (score 3):

A compact table of the German script handwriting can be found here: https://www.archion.de/de/familienforschung/deutsche-schrift/schrifttafel/