# How to read Swiss Church Book / Kirchenbücher Collection Indexes?

Tags: palaeography, switzerland

I recently discovered the Swiss Church / Kirchenbücher book collections, and though you can locate them on [FamilySearch](https://familysearch.org/search/collection/1640373), you have to view them in a LDS Family History center or library.  This creates some additional constraints to me reading and going through them (see below).

For context, the [specific church books](http://www.query.sta.be.ch/detail.aspx?ID=220214) I am wanting to view are listed on the state archives webpage of the canton of Bern as well as [in this breakdown](http://www.ordiecole.com/gen/html/bern_kirch_cd.html) of them. This [document](http://www.brienz.ch/dl.php/de/0do4m-bf6shj/4_Bevoelkerungsgeschichte.pdf) (in German) also has some examples of what the books themselves look like, and look like they would be some effort to go through. I also know I can order scans of each of the book sets by community on CD, but they are [several hundred dollars per CD from Pikton Press](http://www.query.sta.be.ch/detail.aspx?ID=220214), and I lack commercial grade OCR software that I think could both read the hand writing and the German.

Luckily there has been at least one hand written index of them, but I am having a hard time reading them at the library as they do not line up to the [reference documents on Family Search](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Switzerland_Church_Records_(FamilySearch_Historical_Records)#How_to_Use_the_Record).  I am hoping to still extract some value by looking for dates and names, but am not following the format completely of the middle column specifically.  I know they are organized in chronological (date) order. *(Note I do not speak German either and each images can take well over a minute to load at my local FHL)*.

I have been unable to find any typed version of these indexes.

My specific question is: **what are the column headers AND what is the date that doesn't have a column header but seems to be consistently present under most records?**

As a bonus if there is anything else that seems consistent about the records I would appreciate knowing that as well.

This particular example is from a *Toten* or Burial record index.

[image]
[image]

There are *Toten* (Burial), *Taufen* (Baptismal), and *Verkündungs* (Pronouncement/Proclamations???) Indexes.

[image]

Link to [Family Search Burial Template](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/File:Switzerland_Basel_City_Church_Records_(08-0435)_Burial_DGS_4435124_2.jpg) as an example from one of their guides for the above example record which doesn't align.

Comment: Heiraten = marriages, Verkündung are probably the banns -- see German-English Genealogical Dictionary by Ernest Thode, page 264 on [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=q0TJqK5G_ZIC&pg=PA264&lpg=PA264&dq=Verk%C3%BCndung+german+genealogy&source=bl&ots=cTyTdr5RQV&sig=nxA87yWxVtmXtAF0zxsos1qLO-Y&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DQaUVb7WM4LRoASKiJG4Dg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Verk%C3%BCndung&f=false).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First column: “Todtenrodel”, means *list of dead persons*, so these are no birth/baptism records but death records. They consist of a column with a running number and a second column titled „starb“ (*died*, date of death here). Next column: *“Mannspersonen”*, synonyme for (male) human being, contains name and often relationship (*son of ...*, often both parents are named) and birth date (*natus*, Latin for *born*). It's the date you were asking for. Next: “Alter” (*age*) and “begraben” (*buried*, date of burial).

The second column uses old-fashioned names for months, like *Hornung* instead of *Februar* (february). A list of these old names can be found in the article [Monat](http://wiki-de.genealogy.net/Monat) in GenWiki (first table).

I think you need only a limited German vocabulary to understand these records. Maybe 50 to 100 words, most word lists (like [this one from FamilySearch](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/German_Word_List)) contain more words than you will ever need. Concerning the old script: An average German had similar problems like you. The hardest part - for me as well - are the surnames. The rest is much easier. [The book on German handwriting from Roger P. Minert](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6618/learning-german-scripts-handwriting-and-printing-used-in-19th-century-records/6619#6619) should serve you well.

See also my answer at German.SE:  [*Is there a service to help transcribe Kurrentschrift into Latin script?*](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/24117/2626)

Comment: Fixed the spelling of Minert's name.  @CRSouser may want the full reference which you kindly shared with us in http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/6619/1006

Comment: lejonet did not address why the question image did not match the guide template. Simply --- formats change over the years. The guide image was from 1842, the question's image is from 1815. Luckily, the 1815 entries ARE in labelled columns; earlier entries may just be free-form text.